# How to add multiple tables conversion from Excel XLS file to XML ( C# )

Tags: c#, xml, excel, visual-studio

I have downloaded this project from here -->> http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-convert-excel-file-7a9bb404

This one works fine and it's a great commented code to understand even for beginners like myself, but it only works with one table per sheet. Once I add second table in sheet, it throws an error that something is wrong in one of the columns in my spreadsheet:
*It says: " Error occurs! The error message is: Cannot find column 4. "*

Basically, I have this type of tables in my spreadsheet:

[image: Two tables in spreadsheet]

So I want that my program would export those two tables in a single .XML file (just read them both). And those two tables should be separated in two XML childs: the upper one should be *Order-Header* and the lower one - *Line-Items*, like this:

```
<ROOT>
   <Order-Header>
       .....
   </Order-Header>
   <Line-Items>
       .....
   </Line-Items>
</ROOT>
```

This is the code this program has:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace CSOpenXmlExcelToXml
{
    public class ConvertExcelToXml
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Read Data from selected excel file into DataTable
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">Excel File Path</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private DataTable ReadExcelFile(string filename)
        {
            // Initialize an instance of DataTable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Line-Item");

            try
            {
                // Use SpreadSheetDocument class of Open XML SDK to open excel file
                using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, false))
                {

                    // Get Workbook Part of Spread Sheet Document
                    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;

                    // Get all sheets in spread sheet document 
                    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheetcollection = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();

                    // Get relationship Id
                    string relationshipId = sheetcollection.First().Id.Value;

                    // Get sheet1 Part of Spread Sheet Document
                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);

                    // Get Data in Excel file
                    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
                    IEnumerable<Row> rowcollection = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

                    // If there is no rows in the spreadsheet at all, when just return in how it is and output it
                    if (rowcollection.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        return dt;
                    }

                    // Add columns
                    foreach (Cell cell in rowcollection.ElementAt(0))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(GetValueOfCell(spreadsheetDocument, cell));
                    }

                    // Add rows into DataTable
                    foreach (Row row in rowcollection)
                    {
                        // Create temporary row to read rows in spreadsheet
                        DataRow temprow = dt.NewRow();
                        int columnIndex = 0;
                        foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                        {
                            // Get Cell Column Index
                            int cellColumnIndex = GetColumnIndex(GetColumnName(cell.CellReference));

                            if (columnIndex < cellColumnIndex)
                            {
                                do
                                {
                                    temprow[columnIndex] = string.Empty;
                                    columnIndex++;
                                }

                                while (columnIndex < cellColumnIndex);
                            }

                            temprow[columnIndex] = GetValueOfCell(spreadsheetDocument, cell);
                            columnIndex++;
                        }

                        // Add the row to DataTable
                        // the rows include header row
                        dt.Rows.Add(temprow);
                    }
                }

                // Here remove header row
                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                return dt;
            }

            // Throw error message
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                throw new IOException(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Get Value of Cell
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="spreadsheetdocument">SpreadSheet Document Object</param>
        /// <param name="cell">Cell Object</param>
        /// <returns>The Value in Cell</returns>
        private static string GetValueOfCell(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetdocument, Cell cell)
        {
            // Get value in Cell
            SharedStringTablePart sharedString = spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
            if (cell.CellValue == null)
            {
                // If there is no data in cell, just return it
                return string.Empty;
            }

            string cellValue = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
            
            // The condition that the Cell DataType is SharedString
            if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
                return sharedString.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[int.Parse(cellValue)].InnerText;
            }
            else
            {
                return cellValue;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get Column Name From given cell name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cellReference">Cell Name(For example,A1)</param>
        /// <returns>Column Name(For example, A)</returns>
        private string GetColumnName(string cellReference)
        {
            // Create a regular expression to match the column name of cell
            Regex regex = new Regex("[A-Za-z]+");
            Match match = regex.Match(cellReference);
            return match.Value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get Index of Column from given column name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName">Column Name(For Example,A or AA)</param>
        /// <returns>Column Index</returns>
        private int GetColumnIndex(string columnName)
        {
            int columnIndex = 0;
            int factor = 1;

            // From right to left
            for (int position = columnName.Length - 1; position >= 0; position--)   
            {
                // For letters
                if (Char.IsLetter(columnName[position]))
                {
                    columnIndex += factor * ((columnName[position] - 'A') + 1) - 1;
                    factor *= 26;
                }
            }

            return columnIndex;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert DataTable to Xml format
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">Excel File Path</param>
        /// <returns>Xml format string</returns>
        public string GetXML(string filename)
        {
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                ds![enter image description here][2].DataSetName = "Document-Order";
                ds.Tables.Add(this.ReadExcelFile(filename));a
                return ds.GetXml();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I copied all the code because I think it is the easier way to spot where to change it, to read those two tables in one spreadsheet and export them both in one XML file.

Would appreciate any help or just some ideas, how could I archieve this kind of functionality. Thank you.

**UPDATE** This is *MainForm.cs* code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CSOpenXmlExcelToXml
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.btnSaveAs.Enabled = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Open an dialog to let users select Excel file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void btnBrowser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Initializes a OpenFileDialog instance 
            using (OpenFileDialog openfileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openfileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
                openfileDialog.Filter = "Excel files(*.xlsx;*.xls)|*.xlsx;*.xls";

                if (openfileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    tbExcelName.Text = openfileDialog.FileName;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Convert Excel file to Xml format and view in Listbox control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbXmlView.Clear();
            string excelfileName = tbExcelName.Text;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelfileName) || !File.Exists(excelfileName))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Excel file is invalid! Please select a valid file.");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                string xmlFormatstring = new ConvertExcelToXml().GetXML(excelfileName);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlFormatstring))
                {
                    // Line just for checking, if Excel document is empty. If it's true, when just print out an error message
                    MessageBox.Show("The content of Excel file is Empty!");
                    return;
                }

                // Print it in TextView
                tbXmlView.Text = xmlFormatstring;

                // If txbXmlView has text, set btnSaveAs button to be enable
                btnSaveAs.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // General error message checking for errors
                MessageBox.Show("Error occurs! The error message is: " +ex.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Save the XMl format string as Xml file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void btnSaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Initializes a SaveFileDialog instance 
            using (SaveFileDialog savefiledialog = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                savefiledialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
                savefiledialog.DefaultExt = "xml";
                savefiledialog.Filter = "All Files(*.xml)|*.xml";
                if (savefiledialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Stream filestream = savefiledialog.OpenFile();
                    StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
                    streamwriter.Write("<?xml version='1.0'?>" +
                        Environment.NewLine + tbXmlView.Text);
                    streamwriter.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        // Disable maximize button of the form
        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MaximizeBox = false;                           //this is an instance of Form or its decendant
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: It says: " Error occurs! The error message is: Cannot find column 4. "

For some reason it stucks in column 4, although I don't see why it pops up this error message, because my column 4 is " D " column, which is last column of the first table (as I understand this).

Comment: And at what point do you get that error?

Comment: Please add your replies in the original question as well

Comment: I have a basic program form (like in the link I wrote). Basically, when I am trying to convert .XLS(X) file to XML (when I press "Convert" button). I updated a thread with MainForm.cs code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are encountering is that that code assumes that your data is in a single table, I guess it bombs out at either the end of the last column of the top table, or its last row.

The Open XML API is not easy to work with. Most people who have worked with it agree that. You need to do a lot just to get to the stage where you can do pretty basic stuff.

I would suggest you try to use a library that solves some of the issues with the raw API for you.

Why don't you look at [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com)? It is not brilliant and has some annoying bugs when you start manipulating files, but for reading data it should be fine.

Hopefully [this page](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Tables) in the documentation should push you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll look into this. And I'll check your answer as answered, if I didn't get any suggestions to make it work with OpenXML :)

Comment: Cheers. You could make it work with OpenXML, but the question is do you want to?!

Comment: Well, maybe a way to actually make this functionality (to read two tables from excel) with this code and this project.

Comment: And what this code is doing (I mean with ClosedXML)? Converts excel format to XML? I'm asking because I don't see any description in that page about this code.

Comment: ClosedXML is built on top of OpenXML - it allows you to work with the Excel document in a way that is much more like the COM API. There is no conversion involved.